# REGEXP_REPLACE for spark.sql()

Tags: sql, regex, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, regexp-replace

I need to write a REGEXP_REPLACE query for a spark.sql() job.
If the value, follows the below pattern then only, the words before the first hyphen are extracted and assigned to the target column 'name', but if the pattern doesn't match, the entire 'name' should be reported.

Pattern:

1. Values should be hyphen delimited. Any values can be present before the first hyphen (be it numbers,
   alphabets, special characters or even space)
2. First hyphen should be exactly followed by 2 words, separated by hyphen (it can only be numbers,
   alphabets or alphanumeric) (Note: Special characters & blanks are not allowed)
3. Two words should be followed by one or more digits, followed by hyphen.
4. Last portion should be only one or more digits.

For Example:

if **name = abc45-dsg5-gfdvh6-9890-7685**, output of **REGEXP_REPLACE = abc45**

if **name = abc**, output of **REGEXP_REPLACE = abc**

if **name = abc-gf5-dfg5-asd5-98-00**, output of **REGEXP_REPLACE = abc-gf5-dfg5-asd5-98-00**

I have

```
spark.sql("SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(name , '-[^-]+-\\w{2}-\\d+-\\d+$','',1,1,'i')  AS name").show();
```

But it does not work.

Comment: Try it with [regexp_extract](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/sql/index.html#regexp_extract) and the pattern `^(?:[^-\s]+(?=-\w+-\w+\d+-\d+-\d+$)|\S+)` to match the desired strings. See https://regex101.com/r/BeCTRF/1

Answer (score 2):

Use

```java
^([^-]*)(-[a-zA-Z0-9]+){2}-[0-9]+-[0-9]+$
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/frIIga/2/). Replace with `$1`. If `$1` does not work, use `\1`. If `\1` does not work use `\\1`.

**EXPLANATION**

```java
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^-]*                    any character except: '-' (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \2 (2 times):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    -                        '-'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [a-zA-Z0-9]+             any character of: 'a' to 'z', 'A' to
                             'Z', '0' to '9' (1 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ){2}                     end of \2 (NOTE: because you are using a
                           quantifier on this capture, only the LAST
                           repetition of the captured pattern will be
                           stored in \2)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  -                        '-'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [0-9]+                   any character of: '0' to '9' (1 or more
                           times (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  -                        '-'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [0-9]+                   any character of: '0' to '9' (1 or more
                           times (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```

Comment: That seems a better solution +1